# Fancybox afterClose event happens twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am having a very odd problem with Fancybox 2.1.5. The 'afterClose' event is being triggered both before the fancybox opens and after I close it. I only want it to trigger when it is closed. Has anyone seen anything like this? Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modal").fancybox({
            'closeBtn' : true,
            'afterClose' : function(){
                console.log('why');
            }
         });   
});
```

Here is a typical link which triggers the fancybox modal, and uses href as the id of the modal:

```
<a class="modal" href="#editName">Edit Name</a>
```

And here is the actual modal:

```
<div style="display:none" >
    <div class="popop_sec" id="editName">
        {irrelevant stuff here}         
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: It must be something else in your page that is not reflected in your posted code. See http://jsfiddle.net/QDr7b/

Comment: Yes, I will see if I can find any more details to post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. There was a hidden footer include interfering with what I had coded.